# Is it possible to retrieve specific text from a specifically provided website and have a bot send it into the chat using discord.py

Tags: python, web-scraping, discord, discord.py

I'm making a Joke command for my Discord.py Bot, and I was wondering it there is a way to have it go to a joke website, collect all of the jokes and put them an array for it to later randomly choose from.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, but it sounds like a lot of effort for a presumably minor function. I'd try to find a machine-readable list of jokes somewhere, or use a joke API.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could go to a joke website, but that would take longer, unless you really want to do that. If you really wanted to, I would use a Python module such as Beautiful Soup, but that would most likely be more complex, and take longer to get the joke. Instead, I would download a file (Like this [Dad Joke File](https://github.com/yesinteractive/dadjokes/blob/master/controllers/jokes.txt) of jokes I just found and incorporate that into your code. I would look up tutorials on how to use the os module to grab stuff from files, but it's pretty simple overall. Hope this helped.